# How to get data with curl

Tags: http, curl, post, http-headers, http-post

I have a page which i need to submit a number and after that i get data from that number

page is like:
http://page/

and after submit form request URL changes to:
http://page/services/getData

but method is something like:

http://page/services/getData?method=search&1234

can someone helped me to pull data showed in http://page/services/getData?method=search&1234 with curl?

I've already tried:
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \ -d http://page/services/getData?method=search&1234
curl -o http://page/services/getData?method=search&1234
curl --data http://page/services/getData?method=search&1234

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for hours but i just posted the question and i get what i wanted:

curl --request GET --url 'http://page/services/getData?method=search&1234'